# How do I go from a minimum value to a maximum value given a duration?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, statistics

These are my variables:

```
currentPosition = x (can be between minimum and maximum)
startingPosition (aka Minimum) = 0.023
endingPosition (aka Maximum) = 0.608
currentTime = (can be anywhere from 0 to 60)
totalDuration = 60 seconds
```

What I want to do is, in code that is (I want to figure out the math), is start from `startingPosition`, and **add a value to it** *every second* until 60 seconds (`totalDuration`) are **over**. Once over, the `currentPosition` should be equal to the `endingPosition`.

Given that the `totalDuration` can change in my program, but the position min and max stays the same, what could be my formula for `currentPosition` over `totalDuration`?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Does [this](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_interpolation) help you in finding the answer to your problem?